# getDateTimeInstance customized time format

Tags: java, date, date-format

Using this code:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.FULL, new Locale("no")).format(Date);
```

Date `3 AM CST 12 DEC 16` would have a result of: `12. desember 2016 kl 03.00 CST`

But what if I only want to show the hours in the time format and remove the minutes and seconds if ever it was present on other locales?

Expecting a result of `12. desember 2016 kl 03 CST` or if using English locale then should only be `December 12, 2016 3 AM CST`

Answer (score 1):

How about having a `SimpleDateFormatter` like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMMM yyyy aa hh z", new Locale("no"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Actually i am passing different locales for the getDateTimeInstance(). So for other locales they have different formats of their date and time. Thats why i dont think i can use that.

Comment: hmm I'm not quite sure whether you can achieve that with getDateTimeInstance. I just debug the source and seems that your desired format is not available in that flow.